# How does java.util.regex.Matcher::useAnchoringBounds work?

Tags: java, regex

I tried to utilize the Matcher functionality "useAnchoringBounds". But I could not see any effect of setting it from the default value of 'true' to 'false'.

The Javadoc of the Matcher method "useAnchoringBounds" says:

> […] Without anchoring bounds, the boundaries of this matcher's region will not match anchors such as ^ and $. […]

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^a$").matcher("a");
matcher.useAnchoringBounds(false);
System.out.println(matcher.find() + " " + matcher.group());// true a

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^a$").matcher("ab");
matcher.useAnchoringBounds(false);
System.out.println(matcher.find());// false
```

In both examples the setting "useAnchoringBounds" does not influence the match outcome.
How does the "useAnchoringBounds" setting influence the matching?

**Explaining Example**

```
Matcher anchoringBounds = Pattern.compile("^a$").matcher("xax");
    anchoringBounds.region(1, 2);// sub region is: "a"
    assert anchoringBounds.find();// sub region is treated like a complete input by default
    anchoringBounds.useAnchoringBounds(false);// Now treat the region as incomplete part of the whole input
    assert !anchoringBounds.find();// "a" is no longer considered at the beginning of line ^
```

Comment: `a` alone matches with or without anchoring boundaries. Try "xxx**a**yyy" or some other string that does not match `^a$`.

Comment: Yes, in a default regex environment it would match anyway. But as I understand the documentation of the engine option anchors should not match at all in the first example.
Added a second example without this ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key word in the definition of this method is "region".

The region is *part* of the full string, which you can define. For example:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^a$").matcher("xxxayyy");
matcher.region(3, 4);
matcher.useAnchoringBounds(false);
System.out.println("find=" + matcher.find());
```

In this case, we define the region as the "a" inside the "xxxayyy". Now, should the matcher consider the boundaries of this region as anchoring bounds or not?

In the default `true`, it's the same as if you set the matcher's string to just "a", and the pattern will be matched.

But when you set to `false`, it doesn't match an anchored `a`. It considers the region in the context of the whole string.

Comment: Ok, that means "useAnchoringBounds" has an effect only when the Matchers region does not span the whole input.